# Reactjs : Remove outer quotes from JSON after using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am using JSON.stringify on a Json data and after doing this I am getting the " (quotes) at the starting and ending of the data. For eg :

```
x = {fieldId: 536, value: {value: 341, display_value: "ABCD"}}
```

after using JSON.stringify i am getting :

```
x = "{"fieldId":536,"value":{"value":341,"display_value":"ABCD"}}"
```

but the result I desired is "

```
x = {"fieldId":536,"value":{"value":341,"display_value":"ABCD"}}
```

I have tried JSON.parse after stringify but of no use.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I have already mentioned how I need it.

Comment: Can you show the code used to retrieve `x` and to stringify it?

Comment: @ChrisR the code used to retrieve x is :

Comment: x = dataToSend.map( (value, index) => {
      return  {
        "fieldId": idArray[index],
        "value": {
          "value" : value.value,
          "display_value" : value.text
        }
      };
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If you want an object

In the first code block in your question, you show your JS source code.

In the third code block, you show some more JS source code and say that it is what you want.

The two bits of source code give **identical** results. They just use very slightly different JavaScript syntax (in an object literal a property name can be an identifier (like `foo`) or a string (like `"foo"`), which you use makes no difference to the end result).

If you really do want what is in the third code block, then **do nothing**.

Do not use `JSON.stringify`.

---

## If you want JSON

Your second block shows what you *say* you get after using `JSON.stringify`.

This result is impossible.

The most likely explanation for this is that you are inspecting the result using a tool which **displays** a quote before and after the data as a means to indicate to you that the value is a string. The quote characters are not part of the data. You are just misinterpreting what you are seeing.

If you really want a JSON representation of the data in the first code block, then just use `JSON.stringify`.

```js
var x = {fieldId: 536, value: {value: 341, display_value: "ABCD"}};
var json = JSON.stringify(x);
document.write(json);
```

Comment: I want the representation of data in third code block.

Comment: @MayankBansal — Then see the first half of this answer. You already have it.